# React Navigation Causes Error: [Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager.]

Tags: expo, react-navigation, eas

After build my expo project React navigation gives the error of  [Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager.]

In the documentation they mention this error like "This and some similar errors might occur if you have a bare React Native project and the library react-native-safe-area-context library isn't linked.

Linking is automatic from React Native 0.60, so if you have linked the library manually, first unlink it:"
but i am not using bare React native directly build eas